# jquery get new value of list item element

Tags: jquery

I need to get the ID or text value of the new li element with an a class='active'

I have this i jQuery however it returns the previous selected element not the new one

```
$('ul#checkTabs li[class=""]').click(function(){
        console.log($('ul#checkTabs li[class="active"').text());
    });
```

Comment: `$('ul#checkTabs li[class="active"]').next("li").text()`

Comment: Your question is not understood. what do you mean `new` ?

Answer (score 0):

The change to the new active list element happens after your code has finished. But you can just get the text from the clicked element which will be the new active element:

```
$('ul#checkTabs li[class=""]').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```